# set and remove-text-properties seems to have disappeared from Emacs

Tags: text, properties, emacs

I recently updated my MacOS Emacs to

GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0, NS appkit-2113.00 Version 12.0.1 (Build 21A559)) of 2022-09-12

The edit menu used to have a Text-properties element.  That is no longer there and neither is set-text-properties or remove-text-properties.  I use them fairly regularly.  Is there a .elc file somewhere I am missing?  (Though it looks like these might be in C.)

Comment: you might have better luck at emacs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

Emacs (unfortunately, misguidedly in my opinion) removed submenu **Text Properties** from the **Edit** menu, by default.

You need to load library `facemenu` to get the submenu added back:

`M-x load-library facemenu`

Or put this in your init file:

```lisp
(require 'facemenu)
```

For example, it's command **`facemenu-remove-all`** that's menu item **Text Properties** > **Remove Text Properties**.